Testing failing when asserting unit test with bundle
I have the following method:
override fun trackSimulateClicked(entryDate: Boolean, taxDate: Boolean) {
    analytics.trackCustomInteraction(
        screenName = SCREEN_NAME,
        productName = PRODUCT_NAME,
        eventAction = EVENT_ACTION_CLICKED,
        eventLabel = EVENT_LABEL_SIMULATE,
        bundle = bundleOf(
            ENTRY_DATE_KEY to entryDate,
            TAX_DATE_KEY to taxDate
        )
    )
}

...

const val ENTRY_DATE_KEY = "entry_date"
const val TAX_DATE_KEY = "tax_date"

And I'm testing it like this:
@Test
fun `GIVEN Down Payment Analytics WHEN trackSimulateClicked called THEN must track simulate clicked`() {
    downPaymentAnalyticsImpl.trackSimulateClicked(entryDate = true, taxDate = false)

    verify {
        analytics.trackCustomInteraction(
            screenName = "/escolha-data-de-entrada",
            productName = "parcele_facil",
            eventAction = "clicou",
            eventLabel = "simular",
            bundle = bundleOf(
                "entry_date" to true,
                "tax_date" to false,
            )
        )
    }
}

And it's giving the following error:
Verification failed: call 1 of 1: Analytics(analytics#1).trackCustomInteraction(eq(/escolha-data-de-entrada), eq(parcele_facil), eq(simular), eq(clicou), eq(null))). Only one matching call to Analytics(analytics#1)/trackCustomInteraction(String, String, String, String, Bundle) happened, but arguments are not matching:
[0]: argument: /escolha-data-de-entrada, matcher: eq(/escolha-data-de-entrada), result: +
[1]: argument: parcele_facil, matcher: eq(parcele_facil), result: +
[2]: argument: simular, matcher: eq(simular), result: +
[3]: argument: clicou, matcher: eq(clicou), result: +
[4]: argument: null, matcher: eq(null), result: -

I see the problem is with the bundle, but I don't know what the problem is.
Any ideas?
I tried removing the bundle, and it worked. So, the problem's gotta be the bundle.
I also tried like this, and it worked:
@Test
fun `GIVEN Down Payment Analytics WHEN trackSimulateClicked called THEN must track simulate clicked`() {
    downPaymentAnalyticsImpl.trackSimulateClicked(entryDate = true, taxDate = false)

    verify {
        analytics.trackCustomInteraction(
            screenName = "/escolha-data-de-entrada",
            productName = "parcele_facil",
            eventAction = "clicou",
            eventLabel = "simular",
            bundle = any()
        )
    }
}

But I want to test the bundle as well.
